# Mapping a .NET Class to a custom page extension

Tags: asp.net, customization

What I would like to have is a mapping between a custom file extension to a class that is not System.Web.UI.Page but a class of mine that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.

i.e.:

*.aspx -> System.Web.UI.Page
*.my   -> My.Package.MyClass (inherits from System.Web.UI.Page)

I know I can map any extension to be treated like .aspx but I can't find the way to do what I have in mind.

Thanks
d

Answer (score 0):

You need a [ASP.Net HTTPHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28VS.85%29.aspx) for this.

I know you mentioned that you already inherit from System.Web.UI.Page but also look into the lighter weight [ASHX Handler](http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-an-ASHX-handler-in-ASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A custom page handler, but also any ASP.NET Page can inherit from your custom base class, so you wouldn't necessarily need to do a handler.  You could just have the code-behind pages all inherit from My.Package.MyClass instead.

Comment: Yes, it's what I usually do, but I wanted to apply it also when I don't need a separate code file.
I can't use a custom handle because I need markup and asp.net tags.

Comment: Yes, like you mentioned, this would work for ASPX: <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="MyPackage.MyClass" %>  in your original response, you mentioned a custom .my extension, which uses a handler.  You could theoretically point the .my extension to the same PageHandlerFactory class that the .aspx points to, giving you the custom extension and now your new page construct...

Answer (score 0):

I think I was trying to build a castle when I just needed a hut.

When I'm in case of a .aspx page without a separate code file I just have to add the Inherits directive, making it pointing to my custom class, like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="MyPackage.MyClass" %>
```